# How to select a specific JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json

I am requesting some information from an API. I like to use javaScript selectors to grab two specific pieces of data. I'm trying to get two objects from the below JSON:

```
[
  {
    "symbol": {
      "tickerSymbol": "@CH20",
      "vendor": "DTN",
      "marketName": "cbot",
      "symbol": "@C@1",
      "description": "CORN March 2020"
    },
    "last": {
      "number": 380.25
    },
    "high": {
      "number": 382.75
    },
    "low": {
      "number": 379.5
    },
    "open": {
      "number": 382.25
    },
    "bid": {
      "number": 380
    },
    "ask": {
      "number": 380.25
    },
    "close": null,
    "previous": {
      "number": 383
    },
    "cumVolume": 80553,
    "openInterest": 428574,
    "change": {
      "number": -2.75
    },
    "week52High": null,
    "week52Low": null,
    "month": "Mar 20",
    "settleDate": "2020-02-12",
    "settlePrice": {
      "number": 383
    },
    "expirationDate": "2020-03-13",
    "contractHigh": {
      "number": 476
    },
    "contractLow": {
      "number": 365.75
    },
    "quoteDelay": 10,
    "bidDateTime": "2020-02-13T10:40:12-06:00",
    "askDateTime": "2020-02-13T10:40:12-06:00",
    "tradeDateTime": "2020-02-13T10:39:31-06:00"
  }
]
```

Below is what am using after doing `JSON.parse` :

```
var data = JSON.parse(this.response)

     if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400)
     {

         var last = data.last.number
         var change = data.change.number


         console.log(last);
         console.log(change);
         console.log(data);


     }
```

Comment: You forgot about the array around the outermost object in the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First that you have to do is access to the array position of the response data.

In this case `this.response[0]`. Then you can select an specific key of the JSON.

```
var last = response[0].last.number
var change = response[0].change.number

console.log({last}); // last: 380.25
console.log({change}); // change: -2.75
```